# problems with crossdomain.xml, silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, https, crossdomain.xml

For some reason my `crossdomain.xml` is never accepted by Silverlight and I'm getting the `SecurityException` everytime. I'm using SL4 and HTTPS. The server is offline to begin with, the first request fails. After 60 seconds, the client again requests for the `crossdomain.xml`, I return the file, as given below, but I get the security exception. I'm using Fiddler to return the file.

Also interesting is that it works with `clientaccesspolicy.xml` but that is requested only the first time and all subsequent requests only ask for `crossdomain.xml`. The file is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from>      
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>            
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Answer (score 0):

crossdomain.xml file should have another content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the security exception. I'm not sure why does it not request for the clientaccesspolicy.xml again because that works but the crossdomain.xml does not.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this post from SO: [SecurityError when calling a HTTPS-WCF Service from Silverlight 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086589/securityerror-when-calling-a-https-wcf-service-from-silverlight-4/4087353#4087353)

Comment: Samvel the thread above is exactly the same problem as mine. As you must have noticed it worked for him with the clientaccesspolicy.xml, however when there is only a crossdomain.xml it doesn't work. Having a clientaccesspolicy is actually masking the issue. For some reason the crossdomain.xml is not getting accepted, in SL4 if the server is offline to begin with, the client requests for a policy file every 60 seconds, however it only requests for the crossdomain.xml from the 2nd try onwards and that is the whole issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from>      
        <domain uri="*"/>
        <domain uri="https://*"/>
      </allow-from>            
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```